# Weblogic javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException from node manager

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

We have the following error shown in the node manager console.

```
<Warning> <Uncaught exception in server handler: 
 javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090482]BAD_CERTIFICATE alert was r
eceived from 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1. Check the peer to determine why it 
rejected the certificate chain (trusted CA configuration, hostname 
verification). SSL debug tracing may be required to determine the exact 
reason the certificate was rejected.>
 javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090482]BAD_CERTIFICATE alert was 
 received from 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1. Check the peer to determine why it 
 rejected the certificate chain (trusted CA configuration, hostname 
 verification). SSL debug tracing may be required to determine the exact 
 reason the certificate was rejected. at
 com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknown 
 Source)
```

Here are some details on the environment:
Weblogic 10.  We are way past our support license.  However, things seem to work with no issues. Except we started getting this recently.

Questions:
 - Can this be the cause of the following:

```
I can't restart any instance server from the web console app.  Only via some 
command line scripts we are having here.
```

Also, can it be the cause of the following:

```
When I specify system property in 'Server Start' arguments, when I read it 
with 'String sBaseOutputPath = System.getProperty("property.name");' it 
returns null.
```

This problem (that exception trace mentioned above) occurs everywhere, on all our weblogic installations.  Dev, QA, production
and the issues I presented, started recently, and the support license has expired a long-long time ago .. maybe 3 years ago.  This timing confuses me.  It suggest that there must be a way to around the problem.
We are moving to another middle-ware, but while we are redesigning the systems, those running must be kept in shape.

**Can anyone advise on what happens and if there is a way to go around it.**  The major fear is that if for any reason we restart the production machine, we will not be able to start up weblogic services AT ALL !!

Please, help !!

Comment: Have you already checked out this thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/958762 ?

Comment: Thank you.  No, I Haven't seen it before ... 
I am on Windows.  does it mean, I will have to run those two lines

"java utils.CertGen -cn YOURSERVER.DOMAIN.COM -keyfilepass DemoIdentityPassPhrase -certfile mycert -keyfile mykey"

java utils.ImportPrivateKey -keystore DemoIdentity.jks -storepass DemoIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase -keyfile mykey.pem -keyfilepass DemoIdentityPassPhrase -certfile mycert.pem -alias demoidentity